# Reactive (Rx) delta timing, and update as fast as resources allow

Tags: .net, reactive-programming, timedelta

So I'm making a game, And I want to apply physics as often as I can using Rx with .NET.

In a normal, big loop game I'd do it by using a stopwatch to measure elapsed time between loops.

I'd then use that elapsed time to calculate physics.

How would I create something with Reactive to update physics as often as I can? If the computational load increases, I want the physics calculation to just use the bigger steps between updates. I thought of this

```
 Observable.Interval(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 32)).Subscribe(x =>
 {
    //Apply physics code.
 });
```

The problem with that is that if the load drops below 30 frames per second, These events would fall behind and start to stack up, still trying to do the calculations at 30 fps.

Is what I'm trying to do feasable? I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question, I'm new to Reactive, so I'm not sure if one of the many functions available is for this purpose.

Comment: maybe i drop something stupid but wouldn't just an ordinary `if(load < x)` within your subscription solve the problem? So basically, you would end up in your interval handler but nothing would be further calculated if current load is below some threshold.

Comment: I think I understand what you're suggesting, and that's what you do in a normal game loop. But I'm not worried about executing too frequently. I'm worried about when the system slows down more than my specified interval could keep up with. I figured there's a reactive way to accumulate/buffer the stream and calculate on bigger chunks of time if necessary (depending on the load). Hope that clarifies, and hopefully I understood you correctly

Comment: aha, ok, i think i see now what you're after. it seems like you'd still want to have some kind of check if you're below threshold (for each tick) and then if you're not you do your calculus directly and if you are then you might want to look into `reduce` operator in RX library. so effectively, as long as you're below treshold you `reduce` (stack up) incoming values and calculate them once they get above some threshold (or whatever criteria you might have). ref http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/reduce.html

Comment: yeah I think that's looking to be the general area. Clicking on that link led me to ".aggregate" and ".scan"  which sound like possibilities as well. I'll look into them and post the answer if I come up with one. Still not sure how I would define/quantify for the observable what the load is so it can reduce by that much, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: yes, you're right. they are both accumulators but with the difference that `reduce` emits after original observable completes while `scan` emits on every original observable emit. so, `scan` is a better choice, for sure.